# Bounce on Alert OSX in Nodewebkit

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, node-webkit

I am working on a nodewebkit app.
For windows I can alert users by using following code:

```
`window.requestAttention()`
```

But same is not working in OSX to alert users when a notification cames.
`SetBadgeLabel` is working i.e. it is showing label text on app in dock.
But It should bonce on alert on notification similar to what `Skype` does.
Is there anyway this can be fixed?

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you sending any parameters to `requestAttention()` ?

Comment: I tried 1, -1, true in parameters. None of them worked

Comment: i tried 10 and it worked. Did you make sure that the window is not active while testing it ?

Comment: Yes, Window was minimised and It worked for me one only in one scenario, i.e. when a message is received for user when screen is turned off or when user logs in again, but won't bounce instantly